# Why is $1 not working in my bash for loop?

Tags: bash, syntax

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..$1}; do echo 'for the love of god please work'; done
```

but

```
$ ./xgen2 5
```

does not print 'for the love of god please work' 5 times, it prints it once

please 'for the love of god-' please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

`for i in $(eval echo {1..$1}); do echo 'for the love of god please work'; done`

this will evaluate $1 using eval and then utilize that value.

edit:
if you don't want to eval, another option is:
`for i in {$(seq 1 $1)}; do echo 'for the love of god please work'; done`

Comment: I'd like to add that using eval is not the best solution for various reasons, another way to create the range is like this: `for i in $(eval echo {1..$1}); do echo 'for the love of god please work'; done`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need eval

```
#! /bin/bash

for _ in $(seq $1)
do
    echo 'for the love of god please work'
done
```